# Looping copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a workbook to look up if a specific cell has passed a set date and if it has, copy the data from those cells and paste it as values back on top. This is due to the data set it is pulling from can vary week to week and I need it to keep the previous weeks values rather than them change as the data does. All seems to run fine without error but nothing pastes. Pretty new to using loops so may be missing something pretty obvious here.

```
Sub IFLOOP()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B3:B10")
    If cell.Value < Range("B1").Value Then
    Range(cell.Offset(1, 1), cell.Offset(1, 4)).Copy
    cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `cell.Offset(1, 1)` indicates the cell down one row and right one column.  I think you want : `Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 3)).Copy` or `cell.Resize(,4).Copy`

Comment: Tried the change but has made no noticeable difference. I've tried taking out the paste step to see if it just leaves the data copied on the clipboard but it doesn't seem to actually copy anything. Almost feels like the If row isn't picking up that the cell is less than B1

Comment: It may be an activesheet thing.  By not providing the parent sheet you are relying on the active sheet, which many times not what one expects.

Comment: Also your If may be returning false when you believe it should be true.  You will need to step through the code and make sure it is even entering your If statement.

Comment: You wrote `has passed a set date`. If `B1` contains the set date, shouldn't you be using `If cell.Value > Range("B1").Value Then`? You wrote `paste it as values back on top`. For example, for cell `B5` where should what be copied (e.g. `B5:E5` to `B3:E3`)?